# Excel VBA won't save: creating 8-digit alphanumeric "filename"

Tags: excel, vba

I am new to VBA. I am using a "shell" macro to run another macro on a series of files. It won't save. I am going to include my code here and also a series of photos because the photos were the only way to show the result of hovering over the values in the code.

[image: error message]
[image: pathname is correct]
[image: filename is correct]

So, the error message is generating something I don't understand. But it is clear that the links in the code link to what the results should be, so I'm confused.
This is the code:

```
Sub SHELLforMacros()

   Dim wbMatrix As Workbook
   Dim strFileName As String
   Dim strFileName As String
   Dim newFileName As String
   Dim strPath As String
   Dim strExt As String
   Dim objWorkbook As Workbook
   Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim Sheetname As Worksheet
    Set Sheetname = Worksheets(1)
    Dim Worksheet As Worksheet
    Dim rng As Range
    Set rng = Range("A2")

      strPath = "C:\Users\myname\Desktop\All_mricgcm3_files\45\Fall45\test\"
      strExt = "csv"

      strFileName = Dir(strPath & "*." & strExt)

      While strFileName <> ""
      
           Set wbMatrix = Workbooks.Open(strPath & strFileName)
            
         Application.Run "'C:\Users\myname\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Excel\XLSTART\PERSONAL.XLSB'!Graph_NEW"

     strPath = "C:\Users\myname\All_mricgcm3_files\45\Fall45\test\"
           newFileName = Sheetname.Range("A2").Value

        ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs fileName:=strPath & newFileName, FileFormat:=51
        ActiveWorkbook.Close SaveChanges:=True

      Wend

End Sub
```

What this macro is supposed to do is open a file, run another macro on the file (creating a graph), and then save the file with the same name but as an .xlsx file. Then open the next file in the folder and do the same, until it runs out of files. I realize the code may not be the most current. It is cobbled together from things I've found online. Thanks for any help.

Edit: UPDATE - I removed all the section on saving and closing the file from the "shell" macro and put it into the "Graph_NEW" macro. Now the "shell" macro is running fine. But I am running into the **same issue** with the "Graph_NEW" macro now. It is exactly the same error message as highlighted in the first image, only each time there is a new 8-digit alphanumeric "filename" that it is looking for. This seems like a very specific thing.

I changed the section in the following ways, successively, in an attempt to debug. I added `With` and `End With` around the section:

```
With WB
        ActiveWorkbook.Save
        newFileName = Sheetname.Range("A2").Value
        strPath = "C:\Users\qmontana\All_mricgcm3_files\mric45\Fall45\test\"
        ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs fileName:=strPath & newFileName & ".xlsx", FileFormat:=51
        ActiveWorkbook.Close SaveChanges:=True
    End With
```

I changed the name of the folder from "45" to "mric45" thinking that maybe it didn't like a number as a folder name.

I removed the "backslash" at the end of the `strPath`--and then the 8-digit alphanumeric string showed up as an error after the Fall45 folder, like this "C:\Users\myname\Desktop\All_mricgcm3_files\45\Fall45\777GTY78". Yet, as I've shown in the images, all indications are that it knows what file it is working with. There are no "blank spaces" in the pathname.

I tried taking the underscores out of the folder "All_mricgcm3_files".

I moved the line `newFileName = Sheetname.Range("A2").Value` to come before the `strPath` line.

Where is this  8-digit alphanumeric "filename" coming from?? (See error code, first image.)

Comment: Missing `strFileName = Dir()` just before `Wend`.  It would help to outline where this code is running.  If in Personal.xlsb then as noted in your previous question, you do not need to use `Application.Run` - just call `Graph_NEW` directly.  What workbook is `Sheetname` contained in?  Whenever you reference a worksheet it should include a specific workbook qualifier; likewise `Range()` should always have a worksheet qualifier.

Comment: Perhaps add a `& ".xlsx"` as well to the filename.

Comment: Tim, I'll try it. I had it there actually, and took it out. Does anything need to be in the parentheses? As far as calling `Graph_NEW` directly, I explained in the last question that I don't understand. Does it just go there in place of the whole `Application.Run...` line? By itself with nothing around it? I can't run it manually from the Macro Index because I need this to run on 26,000 files. Sheetname is in the `Graph_NEW` file. I can change that but that doesn't seem to be impeding the recognition of the name as shown in the photos above. But I'll give it all a try.

Comment: Will try that too, BigBen.

Comment: So this is the thing- `Sheetname` is in the other macro. It is not a part of any specific WB. It is being used because the name of each `Sheet1` is different in each file. So, the chart name for *each* file is being taken from Sheet1 (Dim Sheetname As Worksheet, Set Sheetname = Worksheets(1)) in *each* file, cell A2.

Comment: I added `strFileName = Dir()`, and `& ".xlsx"` both. Still getting the same error message as in the first image, above.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, it was a very simple thing, in case anyone else runs into this problem.

Took me two days to find out though --> I had somehow dropped a folder layer in the path name. The catch? The alphanumeric string was showing up at the *end* of the path name, not where the folder layer was missing. That's why I was thrown off because my focus was on the ending.

When I added that `folder\` back in, I had no more problem with saving and the macro ran fine.